# Tomcat server "HTTP status 404" on Eclipse, working fine on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am pretty new to all the servers thing so excuse me if I don't have enough knowledge to explain the situation correctly.

Basicly, I run the Tomcat server from my windows computer and it's working perfectly fine, I see the welcome page at localhost. However, when I try to deploy a project and run it with Eclipse, I see the HTTP Status 404 error.

I have read so far plenty of articles and opinions on the internet, some of them I couldn't quite understand, but what I have tried is to switch the server's location. However, when I do that, some SEVERE errors appear in the console, and I'm unable to restart the server except for if I restart Eclipse itself.

This is the full stacktrace:

```
     Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:webproject.filecounter' did not find a matching property.
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.24.0
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Дени\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Дени\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Дени\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Users\Дени\Downloads\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\PSpice;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\PSpice\Library;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\Capture;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\bin;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\OpenAccess\bin\win32\opt;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\fet\bin;C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.3_Demo\tools\pcb\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20;D:\New folder\Downloads\eclipse;;.
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2287 ms
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:45 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [129] milliseconds.
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 02, 2015 5:11:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 956 ms
Aug 02, 2015 5:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/webproject.filecounter] has started
Aug 02, 2015 5:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name [/webproject.filecounter]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject.filecounter]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3746)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@623ebb68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4845)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Users\Дени\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\webproject.filecounter] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Aug 02, 2015 5:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/webproject.filecounter] is completed
```

I'll appreciate any help, but, as I said, I'm pretty new to servlets and I'm sorry if I didn't explain something correctly.

I'm using Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 8.0 versions.

Comment: post the full stacktrace please

Comment: @Deni Hi, can you check the tomcat console whether there is an application with the same name that has been deployed into the server or not? if yes, then you must remove it before you deploy the app through eclipse then try again.

Comment: Hey, kucing_terbang, there's no way such application has been already deployed, because from the first time I've started trying to deploy, it hasn't been working. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It says that the file webproject.filecounter is not valid. Maybe you can try to delete the . metadata.

Comment: Hey, Sean, what do you mean by deleting . metadata? How could I do that?